# Unity editor script that will make a visual object field for an array element and will let me edit it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a script in which I have declared an array of sprites.
I want to represent it in a nice way in the editor and don't want to make it noticeable that it's an array.

This is what my script looks like:

```cs
public class SkinData : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite[] FaceDownSprites = new Sprite[MaxFrameCount];
}
```

And this is what the editor script looks like:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(SkinData))]
public class SkinDataEditor : UnityEditor.Editor
{
    private const float SpriteFieldSize = 100f;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        SkinData skinData = (SkinData)target;

        GUILayout.Label("Tilesheet");
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(skinData.FaceDownSprites[0], typeof(Sprite), GUILayout.Height(SpriteFieldSize), 
        GUILayout.Width(SpriteFieldSize));
        GUILayout.Width(SpriteFieldSize));
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(skinData.FaceDownSprites[1], typeof(Sprite), GUILayout.Height(SpriteFieldSize),
        GUILayout.Width(SpriteFieldSize));
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(skinData.FaceDownSprites[2], typeof(Sprite), GUILayout.Height(SpriteFieldSize),
        GUILayout.Width(SpriteFieldSize));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks to give you an idea of what I wanted to achieve, the arrays won't be visible in the final version

[image]

The problem is it works only partially, it shows the sprites from the array in the newly created fields, but it doesn't let me edit/add sprites. Nothing happens when I drag and drop the sprite to the new field. It doesn't change in the array as well. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
EditorGUILayout.ObjectField();
```

returns the object that you have just assigned. So if you want to keep changes, you should do this:

```
skinData.FaceDownSprites[0] = (Sprite) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(skinData.FaceDownSprites[0], typeof(Sprite), GUILayout.Height(SpriteFieldSize), GUILayout.Width(SpriteFieldSize));
```

And also if you are doing changes on the assets, research these:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.SaveAssets.html

Comment: That makes sense, thought it does much more behind the scenes. It works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695517/7111561)

In general you want to avoid directly going through the `target` **at all**!

This can yield quite some complexity regarding dirty marking and undo/redo handling, prefab overrides, etc.

Rather try to stick to `SerializedProperty` as much as possible and do e.g.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(SkinData))]
public class SkinDataEditor : Editor
{
    private const float SpriteFieldSize = 100f;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        GUILayout.Label("Tilesheet", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        
        serializedObject.Update();

        using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
        {
            var spritesProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(SkinData.FaceDownSprites));

            if (spritesProperty.arraySize < 3)
            {
                spritesProperty.arraySize = 3;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                 spritesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(spritesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue, typeof(Sprite), false, GUILayout.Height(SpriteFieldSize), GUILayout.Width(SpriteFieldSize));
            }
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```